# Are multiple datasets needed in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I have a report where specific part numbers are filtered on a dataset range but I need to add another part number to that report outside of the part filters. Is there a way to query the dataset differently?

I filtered the dataset so I could create calculated fields from the dataset, but now I need another part number to add, but if I add it then the calculated fields with run differently.

ex. I filtered on 300-0000 through 300-9999 so I could create a calculated field to sum them.

However I need to add a 075-0000 through 075-9999, but when I do it would affect the sum of the 300-0000 through 300-9999.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.